# Xcode 12.5 Simulator showing a black screen in macOS 11.2

Tags: xcode, big-sur, xcode-simulator

Xcode Simulator on my MacBook Pro has always worked fine until today, when upon opening it, it shows a black screen for any device selected. Pressing the device's power button does nothing. Restarting the device from the Simulator menu bar does nothing. Resetting the device does nothing. I have Xcode 12.5 installed and macOS Big Sur 11.2. Does anybody know what is happening?

Edit:

I restarted Simulator several times and after a lengthy wait it is now on.

Comment: Could we please close this question? Simulator is working now.

Comment: how did you solve the problem ? I have same issue

Comment: Update your computer and Xcode. Restart simulator a few times. Try closing background applications and CPU-heavy tasks - lack of RAM and CPU will cause Simulator to be slow and sometimes black screen. Oh, and also get a new Mac if you're still running an Intel processor.

Comment: You can delete the question yourself. But I will post an answer from your comment here to help others looking for a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*<sup>As per the Ask Different Meta post [Answer from someone's comment](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4214/489896), I am posting this answer from a [comment from the OP](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/422646/xcode-12-5-simulator-showing-a-black-screen-in-macos-11-2#comment638253_422646). Every content of this answer is from the comment.</sup>*

What made it work :

- Update your computer and Xcode.
- Restart simulator a few times.
- Close background applications and CPU-consuming tasks (lack of RAM and CPU causes the simulator to slow
  down and sometimes display a black screen, as explained in the
  question).
- If you're still running an Intel-based Mac, buy a new one.